# Using `lmap` to filter list of strings

Tags: tcl

Suppose I want to get all the 5-letter words from a list.

```
set words {apple banana grape pear peach}
lmap word $words {if {[string length $word] == 5} {expr {"$word"}} else continue}
# ==> apple grape peach
```

I'm not happy with the quoting mess of `expr {"$word"}`. I was hoping this would work:

```
lmap word $words {if {[string length $word] == 5} {return $word} else continue}
# ==> apple
```

What's an elegant way to "return" a string from the lmap body?

Comment: Wait, why do I think I need to stuff quotes into `expr {$word}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main choices are to use `set` or to use `string cat` (assuming you're up to date). I've split the examples below over multiple lines for clarity:

```
lmap word $words {
    if {[string length $word] != 5} {
        continue
    };
    set word
}
```

```
lmap word $words {
    if {[string length $word] == 5} {
        # Requires 8.6.3 or later
        string cat $word
    } else {
        continue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `set`:

```
lmap word $words {if {[string length $word] == 5} {set word} else continue}
```

or sometimes (if I'm sure `expr` won't reinterpret the value in `word`):

```
lmap word $words {expr {[string length $word] == 5 ? $word : [continue]}}
```

There's this too, of course:

```
lsearch -regexp -all -inline $words ^.{5}$
```

Documentation: [continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm), [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)