# Remove elements with dot extension from list using regex or string matching

Tags: list, tcl, regsub

I'm newbie to Tcl. I have a list like this:

```
set list1 {
    dir1
    fil.txt
    dir2
    file.xls
    arun
    baskar.tcl
    perl.pl
}
```

From that list I want only elements like:

> dir1
>   dir2
>   arun

I have tried the `regexp` and `lsearch` but no luck.

Method 1:

```
set idx [lsearch $mylist "."]

set mylist [lreplace $mylist $idx $idx]
```

Method 2:

```
set b [regsub -all -line {\.} $mylist "" lines]
```

Comment: It looks you might be generating the list from `glob` and might be looking for the directories in that list. Did you know that you can pass the option `-type d` (for directory) to `glob` to get it to do the file type filtering for you? (The converse is to look for type `f` for file.) Very useful!

Comment: I have seen some documentations regarding list of  directory but I'm comfortable with my own idea. Thanks anyways @DonalFellows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 would work if you did it properly. `lsearch` returns a single result by default and the search criteria accepts a glob pattern. Using `.` will only look for an element equal to `.`. Then you'll need a loop for the `lreplace`:

```
set idx [lsearch -all $list1 "*.*"]
foreach id [lsort -decreasing $idx] {
    set list1 [lreplace $list1 $id $id]
}
```

Sorting in descending order is important because the index of the elements will change as you remove elements (also notice you used the wrong variable name in your code snippets).

---

Method 2 would also work if you used the right regex:

```
set b [regsub -all -line {.*\..*} $list1 ""]
```

But in that case, you'd probably want to trim the results. `.*` will match any  characters except newline.

---

I would probably use [`lsearch`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm) like this, which avoids the need to replace:

```
set mylist [lsearch -all -inline -not $list1 "*.*"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The lsearch command has many options, some of which can help to make this task quite easy:

```
lsearch -all -inline -not $list1 *.*
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, filter the list for unaccepted elements using `lmap` (or an explicit loop using `foreach`):

```
lmap el $list1 {if {[string first . $el] >= 0} {continue} else {set el}}
```

See also related discussion on filtering lists, like [Using `lmap` to filter list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489106/using-lmap-to-filter-list-of-strings)

Comment: Thx for the catch (left-over from using `string cat` before).