# How to have tcl switch return a constant value?

Tags: switch-statement, tcl

How do I get a `switch` to return a constant value? For example:

```
set z [switch a { 
    default {expr {{val}}} 
}]
```

This contrived example sets `z` to `val`. Is `expr` the right way to return a constant string from a switch? It's a lot of braces. Is there a better way?

Comment: FYI, similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30489106/7552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For constant expressions, it's not at all bad to use `expr` like that. Otherwise, if you're using Tcl 8.6 then you have `string cat` which will work perfectly for this when used with a single argument.

```
set z [switch a {
    default {string cat "val"}
}]
```

Prior to 8.6 (or with very early point releases of 8.6) you needed to use this instead:

```
set z [switch a {
    default {return -level 0 "val"}
}]
```

That actually works in the right way — it's bytecode-compiled efficiently too — but it has always felt very contrived to me.

---

I tend to put my `set`s inside my `switch`es instead of the other way round, so this specific problem is usually moot for me. However, the techniques described here are extremely useful for the body of an `lmap` call.

Comment: Constant expressions, provided they're not too complex (i.e., they don't use functions), are compiled to true constants in the bytecode.

Comment: Another option for Tcl 8.5 (and early 8.6) is to use `string repeat val 1`

Comment: "I tend to put my sets inside my switches instead of the other way round", so do I

Comment: I adopted this “sets outside” mentality mostly from years of Haskell. I’m surprised how similar the two are.

Answer (score 0):

A more common approach to return a value is to use the set command:

```
set z [switch a { 
    default {set _z val} 
}]
```

Comment: ?  You might want to test first before commenting.